# Application get crashed when the internet is not available

Tags: android

```
private void sendPostRequest(String lo, String la, String username,
                String batlevel) {

            class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
               @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    String lo = params[0];
                    String la = params[1];
                    String username = params[2];
                    String b_level = params[3];

                    System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + lo
                            + " paramPassword :" + la + "Username" + username
                            + "BatLevel" + b_level);

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/Ceylon_Steel/service/markGPSLocation");
           BasicNameValuePair longtiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "latitude", lo);
                    BasicNameValuePair lattiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "longitude", la);
                    BasicNameValuePair username_param = new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "userName", username);
                    BasicNameValuePair batery_level = new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "batteryLevel", b_level);

                    // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request
                    // to as name-value pairs
                    // Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type
                    // safe of NameValuePair
                    List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList();
                    nameValuePairList.add(longtiude);
                    nameValuePairList.add(lattiude);
                    nameValuePairList.add(username_param);
                    nameValuePairList.add(batery_level);

                    try {
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                nameValuePairList);


                        httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                        try {

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                                    .execute(httpPost);

                            // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do
                            // nothing.
                            // So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not
                            // an interface
                            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                                    .getContent();

                            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                    inputStream);

                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                    inputStreamReader);

                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                            }
                            return stringBuilder.toString();

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {

                            cpe.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {

                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                        uee.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    //
                    Log.i("Result", result);

                }
            }

                SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
            sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(lo, la, username, batlevel);
```

In above code i used to send data to server.if the internet is suddenly stopped  while the data is sedning i get following error and get application crashed.So I need Do prevent the application getting crashed.can you tell me how to that

```
01-08 12:30:42.811: W/System.err(6285): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-08 12:30:42.831: W/System.err(6285):     at
```

Answer (score 3):

you can check if there internet connection or not

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    try{
          ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Actully this code run as a background service.It sends the parameters to the server every 5 seconds.I test above code still gives the error when the internet connection is off suddenly

Comment: try give catch(Exception e){} after catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                        uee.printStackTrace();
                    }

Answer (score 1):

use try catch and caught exception `ConnectTimeoutException` and display you desired result there.

Comment: This is the proper solution. By checking on this exception you can report network issues to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Check Internet before call sendPostRequest() method.

this method checks whether mobile is connected to internet and returns true if connected:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (ni == null) {
   // There are no active networks.
   return false;
  } else
   return true;
 }
```

in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has its own answer. Your getting a SocketException so handle that exception. The best way to handle it would be adding a catch clause at the end to handle all exceptions. Sample code :

```
     catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {

                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {

                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                    uee.printStackTrace();
                }

   catch(Exception e)
   {
     //You got a error, diaplay error msg to user here
   }
```

Put that code at the end and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code to check if my Internet connection is working or not.

```
public abstract class NetworkUtils {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

You need to define following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Actully this code run as a background service.It sends the parameters to the server every 5 seconds.I test above code still gives the error when the internet connection is off suddenly

Comment: You don't need to check internet connection in your case as it will never help your case. You need to handle exception and show error to user. Check my answer below !

Answer (score 0):

```
 increase socket timed out
     // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 8000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 10000;
```